# Use Maven to build cross compilation for mac, window, linux

Tags: linux, windows, macos, maven, cross-compiling

I wonder if it is feasible to use maven to build cross compilation for mac, windows, and linux. It is for building a ODBC client project. Currently, I have separate make files for 32, 64bit, linux and mac.

Please, offer any advantages and disadvantages you might think of.

We use C/C++, gcc49, gdb.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Which compiler/programming language did you have in mind?

Comment: @Biffen Hi, currently using C/C++, gcc49, gdb Thanks.

Comment: Pehaps [nar-maven-plugin](https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin) can do what you want.